# Возможно ли создать один макет для всех товаров (для просмотра характеристик),или нужно создвать Activity под каждый товар?

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение для Android в котором основная цель-просмотр товара и его характеристики. У меня будет где-то 800-1000 товаров.Возник вопрос:нужно ли создавать Activity под каждый товар? Или можно как-то создать один макет для всех товаров , а потом заполнять?Или есть другие варианты? Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно это сделать ,и что для этого нужно?

Comment: не только можно, но и обязательно нужно. Одна активити с одним макетом используется для вывода всех однотипных данных. В случае товаров это будет либо локальная БД, либо сетевой запрос из которых вы получаете данные и заполняете ими соответствующие поля на макете.

Comment: Рекомендую вам, прежде чем начинать что то писать, сначала прочитать какую то базу по разработке, например замечательную книгу Б.Филлипса "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", где вы найдете всю необходимую вам информацию по разработке на примерах конкретных приложений, в том числе и ответ на этот вопрос с полноценным работающим примером.